# Writing in a text file, without overwriting, it in C #

Tags: c#

I would like to know if it is possible to write in a text file without overwriting its current contents and without creating or merging Lists of string etc. So lets say i run the program once and i write Hello , and when i run it again i write Everyone so the txt has now Hello Everyone. Moreover, does anyone know how to read only a specific block of line from a file, for example from , to , or from Dear to Best Regards etc. Thanks a lot in advance!!! I hope that my question is clear enough

Comment: Yes, its possible.  Have you tried to do it?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To append text to a file you can use the methods [`File.AppendText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx) or [`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can open the file in Append Mode, which will create the file if it doesn't exist, and append if it does.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx

As for the second part of the question, it depends on how big the file is I guess. If it was small I'd read the whole thing in and examine it for the line or block I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(string path, string contents)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! It solved my problem. Same to all previous answers. i dont want to repeat the comment !! :)